# Tricky 1-to-1 unowned relations query

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I am currently developing a location based service on GAE/Java. I am quite new to this and I need your help with the JDO query part.

I have two persistent classes, Client and ClientGeolocation. The first one is for storing the client attributes (Key clientId, String name, String settings, etc.) and the second is for storing its geolocation updates (Key clientGeolocationId, Key clientId, Long timestamp, Double latitude, Double longitude). Since one client has thousands of geolocation records (one for each location update) over time, I decided to use 1-to-1 unowned relationship between ClientGeolocation and Client classes.

The service lets the user to see if another user is within range (e.g. they are in 5 minutes walking distance). Making this happen with JDO queries for each request would be far too resource consuming / slow so I put the last geolocation of the users in memcache and do the checking from there. So far so good.

The problem is when the App cold starts and memcache is empty, I want to fill up the memcache with data from the storage (using JDO query) and I simply do not know how to query "the last geolocation record for each user who has at least one record which is not older than 180 minutes".

The best possible solution I can come up with at the moment is to do this in two parts. First, to query the clientId keys of users who has records within the last 180 minutes (this will query distinct clientIds I hope) then execute a query for all clientId in which I query the last (top 1 order by timestamp desc) geolocation record. This means if the first query returns 10.000 users then I will do 10.000 queries for the last geolocation records. I have a feeling that there is a better solution for this in GAE :) .

Can you please help me how to write this query in a proper way?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Should this be helpful ?
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_0/jdo/jdoql_subquery.html